# I have a strange space character in a String

Tags: java, whitespace

I have a Java method that looks for a word inside a phrase, and if it finds the word then it removes it from the phrase. The word and the phrase can be anything. They're variant. Here is my code :

```
private String removeWord( String phrase, String word ) {
    phrase = phrase.replaceAll( "(?i)" + word , "" );
    return phrase;
}
```

The problem I have is that there is a phrase passed to this method :

> The ancient Roman Empire was so vast, so mighty and so ambitious that it had a powerful effect on
>   nearly everything that it touched. Rome’s influence was so widespread that even today, the languages, cultures,
>   laws and governments of most Western nations still bear Rome’s mark.

And the word to find and remove from the text is "Roman Empire", but it couldn't delete it. After some investigation I found this was because the spaces in the phrase were not normal spaces. When I copied the phrase's text in Notepad++ and searched for the same word, I couldn't find it too !

See the attached screenshot. Line 5 is a line I wrote manually and as you see Notepad++ was able to find it, but it couldn't find the "Roman Empire" in Line 1. When I counted "Roman Empire" in the file it only found it once !

**What's that other strange space ?!**

[image]

**----------------------------------------------------- >>  Edit: More details :**

I wrote this code in Java to check the difference between the 2 spaces :

```
char a = ' ';
char b = ' ';

System.out.println( (int) a );  // Prints 160
System.out.println( (int) b );  // Prints 32
```

The strange thing is that the 2 spaces look the same exactly !

Comment: It would really help if you could produce a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem. It's hard to tell different whitespaces apart in a screenshot...

Comment: Where are you getting that phrase from??

Comment: Load the file in a programming language and look at the code points in a debugger.

Comment: @Jon .. I understand that. All i am asking about is a way or a guide to know how to detect different space characters. I will update my question to make this clear.

Comment: Instead of looking at the file with a text editor, you'd better open it with an HexEditor, for example http://frhed.sourceforge.net

Comment: Since you are using notepad++, go to View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters, and then you will see what kind of whitespace it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [a non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). You can look explicitly for them or replace your search string spaces by \s (aka [:space:]).

Comment: Hey that sounds like an easy answer but I'm sure more than one of us gone crazy before finding out what was happening! :-D Thanks to your answer and other's, and also our own experience at HeavyDots dealing with it, we've got enough information and wrote a both funny and explaining post about it! =) http://heavydots.com/blog/when-the-white-space-became-a-beast